# How to read shape files on Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any library to read and write shape files (*.shp) and dbf file from internal storage or isolated storage in windows phone 8 SDK?

Answer (score 0):

There are no ESRI SHP file readers that are included in the standard toolkit for Windows Phone.  You can write your own reader, search for a library that will work with WP, or someone else may have an idea of how to do this.

From here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/7d2eb822-b871-4c02-9cf2-3bf5b0d1add2/windows-phone-8-it-is-somehow-possible-to-read-a-shape-file-and-display-on-windows-phone-8-map

Looks like Syncfusion can:
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/maps